# python widget creation using self on button

Tags: python, widget, pyqt, pyside, self

I was hoping some one could explain to me the difference and reason behind why I keep coming across two different methods for which people place buttons into the widget? I sometimes see

```
button = Button('Button', self)
```

or

```
self.spinner = QtGui.QSpinBox()
```

I just want to know whats the difference, is one more beneficial than the other? When to use which in what scenarios and why? Does the position of 'self' affect this in the widget some how?

Comment: This looks like it's from two completely different widget frameworks. (The second one is clearly Qt, the first one is probably not.) And different frameworks work differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only care about PyQt and PySide…

There are two different places that `self` appears in your examples, which mean very different things.

---

First, as an argument to the constructor:

Every widget's constructor has a `parent` parameter, with a default value of `None`.

There are three reasons to leave out the parent:

- You're going to assign the widget to a layout or other parent after creation.
- You're creating a top-level window.
- You're creating a special-purpose widget like `QDesktopWidget`.

If none of these are true, you need to pass a parent. If `self` is a widget, and the thing you're creating is a child of that widget, you will pass `self` as the parent.

Here's an example of the first alternative:

```
self.spinner = QtGui.QSpinBox()
hbox = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
hbox.addWidget(self.spinner)
self.addLayout(hbox)
```

We can't pass a parent to `QSpinBox` at construction time because its parent doesn't exist yet. So, we leave it off, and `addWidget` it to a layout object later.

This is all explained early in most tutorials for PySide or PyQt, like [First programs in PySide](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/firstprograms/) and [Layout management in PySide](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/layoutmanagement/).

---

Meanwhile, one of your examples stores the widget in `self.spinner`, making it an instance attribute on `self`, which means we can refer to it later. For example, if some other method (like the signal handler for a button) wants to adjust the spinner's value, it can access it as `self.spinner`.

If you will never need to refer to the child widget in your code after the current function, you don't need to store it.

This part is explained in the [Classes](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html) chapter in the Python tutorial.

Comment: I appreciate the great answer. I am currently getting into python coming from another language and I was unclear what all this meant. Thank you very much and I'll look into the links you sent for more information.